keditor5 HTML embed content disappears when I go back to edit
We recently upgraded from ckeditor 4 to ckeditor 5.
We have some complex tables in our pages (header rows alternating with body rows) that are modified by ckeditor 5's filtering mechanism (all header rows are moved to the top).
I installed the ckeditor 5 HTML Embed module that should let me keep my tables but the HTML snippet disappears every time I go back to editing.
Many thanks for your help.

I click the HTML embed icon to add a HTML snippet and insert some code (can be any code, even just a simple div tag),
I click the green tick (Save changes) and I click the page SAVE button.
I can see the page with the content appearing as expected.
I edit the page again and the HTML snippet is gone,
If I go back to the page and refresh, the content is still there. But when I edit, it's disappeared. Whatever I put in the snippet, same thing happens.

